# JQuery AJAX GET request always returns error

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, rest, mlab

I'm learning web development and am trying to make an ajax request to query a MongoDB database hosted in MongoLab via their [REST API](http://support.mongolab.com/entries/20433053-rest-api-for-mongodb). My code is very simple, but I don't understand why the ajax request always go to the error. Help?

```
<doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.1.0.min.js"></script>

    <title>Data Viewer</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="the_form" method="post">
        <input type="submit" value="Go" />
    </form>

    <script>
        $(function() {
            $('#the_form').submit(function() {
                $.ajax({
                    url: 'https://api.mongolab.com/api/1/databases/omnitor-android/collections/logs?apiKey=[some API key in here]',
                    type: 'GET',
                    success: function(data) {
                        alert(data);
                    },
                    error: function() {
                        alert("boom");
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: If you are making a cross-domain request you need to include this at the end of your `url`: `&callback=?`.  The callback name may not be callback; you'll have to check with the API to see what it actually is.

Comment: what is happening ,is your alert("boom') executing every time ??

Comment: ^yes it shows boom everytime

Comment: The error function should be able to accept arguments among which are the contents of the response.  Could you try printing those out instead of just "boom"?

Comment: I did try that earlier. My success function's signature was `function(data, textStatus, xhr) {...}` and the error was `function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {...}` but when I printed out the `textStatus` inside error, it simply contained the string "error."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because of you are trying to call a service hosted in different domain.Ajax is not allowing cross domain requests because of the [Same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy). you cannot use ajax to call external sites. if you really want to use, you have to use [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP). Or you can use serverside proxy for this. means, call external site in the server side and do ajax call to the that webservice.

For more details on how to do the cross domain ajax requests follow [this link](http://tutorials.cmsnsoftware.com/2012/02/how-to-use-cross-domain-ajax-request.html#0).

Comment: I tried to add a line `dataType: "jsonp"` to the ajax request. It doesn't execute `alert("boom");` anymore but neither does it show the returned JSON in a dialog. :(

Comment: no point of setting data type to json if you havent follow any steps of the link. so go through the link you can understand what need to be done

Comment: Unfortunately though, MongoLab doesn't support JSONP: https://support.mongolab.com/entries/20676708-JSONP-support

Comment: so you can use server side proxy for this. create a proxy web service inside your site and access the Mongolab using it. and then use ajax request to get data from your local server service.

Answer (score 2):

The MongoLab REST API has full support for CORS so most browsers should be able to make requests to it without an issue.  Try adding this to the top of your js code:

```
$.support.cors = true;
```

Have you tried using the debugging console built into most browsers (e.g. FireBug)?  You might be able to find a more detailed error message there.

Also, please feel free to contact support@mongolab.com for assistance.

Answer (score 0):

It is not working because of the [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) constraint imposed on ajax requests. Same origin policy prevents browsers from making cross domain requests.

A solution to this problem is to use the [jsonp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP). Most of the API providers supports this and libraries like jQuery also supports this protocol.

If you inspect your browser console you can find something like

```
Origin http://fiddle.jshell.net is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
```

You can use [jQuery.getJson()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) like

```
$.getJSON('https://api.mongolab.com/api/1/databases/omnitor-android/collections/logs?apiKey=[some API key in here]?callback=?', function(data) {
    console.log('xx')
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Mongolab does support CORS. This means you won't get much support in IE* and Opera (http://caniuse.com/cors). To use it for browser supporting CORS, you have to make sure you to set the dataType to "json" in your jQuery ajax request.

```
      $.ajax(
            {
                url         : url
            ,   type        : "GET"
            ,   dataType    : "json"
            ,   success     : function( data )
                {
                    // do something
                }
            });
```

For more browser support I suggest to use a simple proxy (in PHP for instance). 
You can than use something like;

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  if ( ! "withCredentials" in xhr) {
    // Use proxy in ajax call
    //
  }
  else {
   // Standard CORS call
   // 
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

There are three ways to overcome same-origin policy restrictions:

1. CORS (Cross Origin Resource Sharing) - although requires some additional configuration on the service provider's server side, it is the most ideal solution, especially in your case since MongoLabs does offer support for this method -no extra work on the developer's end.
2. Server side proxy - Create a local server that routes your requests to the original server . Although requires work on your end to configure a server, it will help you avoid same-origin policy restrictions altogether.
3. JSONP (Java Script Object Notation with padding - In my opinion this should be a last resort due to the security risks associated with this approach and also the limitations of having to stick to one HTTP verb(GET) for all your requests.