# Retrieving data from MongoDB with ExtJS using the REST API

Tags: mongodb, rest, extjs, get, httprequest

For the need of a simple demonstrator, I've created a simple grid panel in ExtJS, and now i'm trying to fill it with data coming from MongoDB. I heard about Node.JS and stuff but there I just want to use the REST API of MongoDB to retrieve the data.
Note : I'm new in ExtJS and REST request.

My problem is that when loading my page, there is no panel created and firebug tells me :
""NetworkError: 400 Bad Request - http://xxx.xxx.xx.xx:28017/mydb/device/find?_dc=1374225874880&page=1&start=0&limit=25""

If I copy and paste the URL http://xxx.xxx.xx.xx:28017/mydb/device/find?_dc=1374225874880&page=1&start=0&limit=25  I can see the data, so that means that the Mongo data are accessible through URL.
Note that I dont' know where the "page=1&start=0&limit=25" param of the URL comes from, it wasn't implemented by me.

My code that is supposed to load the data is in my Store component of my MVC :

```
Ext.define('AM.store.Users', {
extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
model: 'AM.model.User',
autoLoad: true,
proxy: {
    type: 'rest',
url: 'http://xxx.xxx.xx.xx:28017/mydb/device/find',

    reader: {
        type: 'json',
        root: 'rows',
    idProperty: '_id'

    }
}
});
```

And this is what shows the Mongo URL :

```
{
"offset" : 0,
"rows": [
 { "_id" : "SheevaPlug", "manufacturer" : "GlobalScale" }
],

"total_rows" : 1 ,
"query" : {} ,
"millis" : 0
}
```

The mapping in the Model seems correct too :

```
Ext.define('AM.model.User', {
extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
fields: ['_id', 'manufacturer']
});
```

Thanks by advance if you can help me !
Cheers,

Vincent

Comment: possible duplicate of [JQuery AJAX GET request always returns error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14722526/jquery-ajax-get-request-always-returns-error)

Comment: It's likely that you're trying to do a cross origin call, which isn't supported by the admin interface provided by MongoDb. It works when you paste it because then the browser is making a direct call.

Comment: Ok, so I guess it's better to use NodeJS anyway ! Thanks dude :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Node.js to create MongoDB web services that you will call with Sencha.

Comment: Ok, I'll guess this is what I need to do :(